ActionSet Failed template: config:6:59: executing "config" at <.Profiles>: can't evaluate field Profiles
In my kanister backup, i tried to use blueprints to better prepare my elasticsearch db for backup. But, for some reason, my blueprint cannot access to '.Profiles' value in last command inside official Blueprint for elastic
The command:
**gzip -c /backup | kando location push --profile '{{ toJson .Profiles }}' --path "${backup_file_path}" --output-name "kopiaOutput" -**

As per my undestanding it should read a profile which is already presented on kasten and can bee seen from Dashboard.
Thank you in advance!
